# Can't locate element with selenium to slot game icon

Tags: python, selenium

I am working on a selenium script in Python, where I am on this stage trying to locate a game icon.

But I can't locate it and click.

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZjL5.png)

This is what I've tried:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/ul/li[17]/a/img')
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="jackpot_01001"]")
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gameList_SLOT_01001"]')
self.driver.find_element_by_id("jackpot_01001").click()
```

But it will show:

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[5]/ul/li[17]/a/img"}
> (Session info: chrome=93.0.4577.82)

Comment: can you share the link of the page source, I might be able to help you better.

Comment: Your third locator should work `//*[@id="gameList_SLOT_01001"]`. Please add a wait, or check if it is in an `iframe`. Or can you share link?

Comment: Sorry I can't share the link for you. 
I has added the wait, but it not work.
But I upload new photo on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[5]/ul/li[17]/a/img"} (Session info: chrome=93.0.4577.82)
```

implies that Either one of the following :

1. Element locator is not correct.
2. Element is in **iframe**.
3. Element is in **shadow root**.

I am not sure if `//li[@id='gameList_SLOT_01001']` or `/html/body/div[5]/ul/li[17]/a/img` is unique or not. You need to check in HTML DOM.

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

If it happens to be a unique node, then put some waits and then perform the click.

**Update 1:**

There are 4 ways to click in Selenium.

I will use this xpath

```
//li[@id='gameList_SLOT_01001']/descendant::img
```

**Code trial 1:**

```
time.sleep(5)
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@id='gameList_SLOT_01001']/descendant::img").click()
```

**Code trial 2:**

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@id='gameList_SLOT_01001']/descendant::img"))).click()
```

**Code trial 3 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@id='gameList_SLOT_01001']/descendant::img")
self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**Code trial 4 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@id='gameList_SLOT_01001']/descendant::img")
ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

**Update 2 :**

Since it's a new tab, you would have to switch to it first before interacting with any web element on this new tab.

```
self.driver.find_element_by_id('RTGWEB-RTGWEB').click()
time.sleep(5)
self.driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
time.sleep(5)
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@id='gameList_SLOT_01001']/descendant::img").click()
```

Comment: thank you
I had checked that. the result is unique node.
And I also check iframe, it is not iframe.
I can't find the iframe in this page.

Comment: @WilliamsLai : `//li[@id='gameList_SLOT_01001']` and  `/html/body/div[5]/ul/li[17]/a/img` both of them are unique in HTMLDOM ? I can give you optimize solution based on this question.

Comment: Yes,
both of they are unique.

Comment: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//li[@id='gameList_SLOT_01001']/descendant::img"}
  (Session info: chrome=93.0.4577.82)

It still appear this message

Comment: Did you try all 4 ways  ?

Comment: yes, in addition to 2nd will show 
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Is this opened in a new tab ? How did you navigate to this element  ?

Comment: Yes, gameList_SLOT_01001 is a new tab.
i will click the other icon to open the new tab,and gameList_SLOT_01001 is in the new tab